# How does one show that if $B \subset A$ (where $A$ is a directed set) is cofinal in $(A, \leq)$ then $(B, \leq)$ is a directed set?

Tags: general-topology, order-theory, nets

First two axioms of directed sets readily follow for $(B,\leq)$ by the virtue of being a subset of $(A,\leq)$ but I don't see how the third one follows.

Directed set $(A,\leq)$ is a set with the order relation $\leq$, where the order relation $\leq$ is reflexive, transitive and that every pair of elements has an upper bound in $(A,\leq)$.

By "$B$ is cofinal in $A$.", I mean, that each element of $A$ is bounded above by some element of $B$.

Comment: What assumptions do you have on $A$? I mean, you could take a set $A$ that is not directed, and $B=A$ would be cofinal in $A$ and not directed, so you must have *some* hypotheses on $A$. What are they?

Comment: (Also, not everyone defines things identically; I don’t know what the “axioms of directed sets” you have, or how you order them. Unless you expect us to read your mind (and the government gets really annoyed when I do that without a warrant), it’s impossible to know what you are asking.)

Comment: ok wait I'll add more details, sorry about this

Comment: If you are going to say “reflexive and transitive” explicitly, surely you are missing anti-symmetry.

Comment: Anti-symmetry is not an axiom that I am using

Comment: @ArturoMagidin In my experience, it's very common to allow non-antisymmetric preorders to count as directed sets to be used as index sets in nets.  For example, the net where the index set is $\{ (U, x) \mid U \subseteq X \land U \in \mathcal{T}_X \land x_0 \in U \land x \in U \}$ ordered by reverse inclusion of $U$, and the net is $(U, x) \mapsto x$.

Comment: It is precisely for nets

Comment: @DanielSchepler: I wouldn’t say it is *ordered* by reverse inclusion; it is pre-ordered, sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\leq$ is a partial order on $A$, it is a partial order, by restriction on any subset; this is a property of partial orders, directed or not.

Let $b_1,b_2\in B$. Since $A$ is directed, there exists $a\in A$ such that $b_1\leq a$ and $b_2\leq a$. Since $B$ is cofinal in $A$, there exists $b\in B$ such that $a\leq b$. Thus, there exists $b\in B$ such that $b_1\leq b$ and $b_2\leq b$. Hence, $B$ is directed.

Comment: Oh god, thanks for your help, now that I see it, its not difficult.